# Multi-column custom sort

Tags: yadcf

I am using datables with yadcf. I am trying to implement a custom sort for some of my columns that always sorts first by a different column.

For example, clicking on the header for Column B should always sort first by Column A, then Column B.

As far as I can tell providing a custom sort function won't work for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: yadcf is only for filtering, its sits on top of datatables for filtering only, sorting of columns and all other  features are implemented in datatables itself, [read yadcf description](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf#description)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the fast response. I misunderstood and thought the sort parameters related to sorting of the data, not the filter values. Thanks also for the plugin, it's been very useful to me.